# How do I use a .bat file to start a .pyw script without cmd popping up?

Tags: python, batch-file

I want to use a .bat file to run a python script without a command prompt showing up.
I've read that saving the script as .pyw should do the trick but somehow command prompt keeps showing up.

My .bat file looks like this:

```
@C:\Users\path\to\pythonw3.8.exe C:\Users\path\to\script.pyw
```

The python script does nothing but creates a simple shelve file:

```
import os, shelve

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\Coding\Project-Updatable_Multi-Clipboard')
success = shelve.open('success')
```

When I double-click the .bat file the python script itself works as intended but for some reason, a command prompt shows up for a split second.
I've tried exchanging "pythonw3.8.exe" in the .bat file with "pythonw3.exe" and "pythonw.exe" but I get the same behaviour as with plain "python.exe".

Do I have to modify the .bat file or the .pyw script in order to run the script without the command prompt popping up?

Comment: Why do you use a batch file after all? Instead you could create a shortcut with exactly the target path in your batch file (without the `@`)…

Comment: I'm using a batch file since it is the only way I know how to start a python script with win+r and without opening cmd. What exactly do you mean by "create a shortcut with exactly the target path"? The path in the batch file leads directly to my python script. So far I've used the @ since I didn't know that it was unnecessary.

Comment: By shortcut I meant a `.lnk` file (right-click, New, Shortcut), with `C:\Users\path\to\pythonw3.8.exe C:\Users\path\to\script.pyw`. (The `@` in a batch file suppresses command echoes…)

Comment: I've just created such a shortcut and this seems to fix the problem. The python script runs as intended and cmd does not show up. How come this works but the method using a batch file fails? Is this a limitation concerning batch files in general?

Comment: CMD.exe executes the batch file which will always open a console window.

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't make that connection but now it seems quite obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Squashman pointed out .bat files are interpreted by cmd.exe. As a result a

> batch file which will always open a console window

regardless of whether a .pyw script or a .py script is run or not.

As @aschipfl explained creating a shortcut (.lnk file) like this:

```
C:\Users\path\to\pythonw3.8.exe C:\Users\path\to\script.pyw
```

is an easy solution to launch a .pyw script without a command window opening.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use Echo command at start your batch code:

```
@echo off
@C:\Users\path\to\pythonw3.8.exe C:\Users\path\to\script.pyw
```

Comment: It's not the output of the batch, the `cmd.exe` window is the problem and that will still be opened with your solution